# "What's up doc?" - Is Bugs Bunny impersonating someone?

Tags: dialogue, reference, looney-tunes

It turns out that [Bugs Bunny was impersonating someone when he ate the carrot](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/was-bugs-bunny-impersonating-someone-when-he-ate-the-carrot).

Was he also impersonating a contemporary actor when he asked ***What's up doc?*** or is that a Bugs Bunny original?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The first time Bugs uses the phrase is in the cartoon [Wild Hare
>   1940](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wild_Hare). The rabbit walks up to Elmer Fudd who is hunting for him
>   with a large gun and casually asks, “What’s up Doc?”

It's their original phrase. May be inspired from `What's up Phrase`
which appears previously

> The phrase appears in Jack London's The Sea Wolf (1904), chapter 25
>   (-- "What's up?" I asked Wolf Larson.--)
>
> Another referance to 'whatsup' can be found in a short story The
>   Adventures of Shamrock Jolnes from the collection Sixes and Sevens
>   (1911) by acclaimed American short story writer O' Henry (1862-1910).
>   The character Shamrock Jolnes says, "Good morning, Whatsup."

Answer (score 26):

The (co-)Creator of *Bugs Bunny*, [**Tex Avery**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tex_Avery), once [said](http://www2.warnerbros.com/spacejam/movie/cmp/lineup/bugs.html):

> *We decided he was going to be a smart-aleck rabbit, but casual about it, and his opening line in the very [first one](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWildHare) was `Eh, what's up, Doc?` And, gee, it floored [the audience]!*
>
> *They expected the rabbit to scream, or anything but make a casual remark--here's a guy with a gun in his face! It got such a laugh that we said, 'Boy, we'll do that every chance we get.' It became a series of 'What's up, Docs?'.*
>
> *He was the most timid of animals, yet he had courage and brashness. **The whole gimmick was a rabbit so cocky that he wasn't afraid of a guy with a gun who was hunting him.***

The phrase *"What's up, doc?"* was used at [his High School](https://jonathanrosenbaum.net/2022/03/30521/).

> **Remembering the *‘What’s up, Doc?’* expression from his high-school days** in Texas, Avery had decided to place it in the mouth of a sharp Brooklynese rabbit who knew everything.